# Looking For Ragnarok Online Knight Tips/Builds

Tags: ragnarok-online

i just started playing Ragnarok Online on a retail Brasilian Server ( Hosted by LevelUpGames ).
After talking to some friends that play RO i decided to start in `Way of Knights playstyle.`

My aim is to play with Pikes after "reseting" (or whatever you guys may call it).

Since i just started and my level is Base 19, i need some tips.

1 - Whats the Mobs Level Difference i should aim when leveling ? (EG: Fight Mobs that are 10 Levels Above mine ? ). I know there is a table that explains the bonus [here][1] but i can't handle by myself

2 - People say that i must level as a two handed sword Knight, using AGI,DEX and STR as my main attribs. Is it that faster to level that way instead of leveling using pikes ?

3 - Where can i find decent gear/weapons while leveling ? Is there any spot that i might visit to get some gear before a certain level ?

4 - Are Knights with Pikes, good for PvP or Two Handed Swords ones are Better ?

Extra-Question: When is Ragnarok Online 2 Going Public ?

These are my questions,sorry to get them all together in a single Thread.

Thanks in advance for everyone :D

Comment: from what I remember, pike knights were great for pve and so so for pvp, but that's a very very long time ago so don't take my word for it

Comment: It ALL depends on the rates of the server you're playing, so without knowing that, not much can be said.

Comment: I don't really think that the PVP part of my question,have something to do with the rating of the server,but, the server i mentioned, is 1x rating. It is designed to be the official ragnarok server of Brasil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - Whats the Mobs Level Difference i should aim when leveling ? (EG:
>   Fight Mobs that are 10 Levels Above mine ? ). I know there is a table
>   that explains the bonus [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/561051-ragnarok-online/faqs/21546) but i can't handle by myself

Experience and mob level aren't proportional.

You want to follow a leveling guide. These tell you what the very best monsters for your level - the ones with highest EXP taking into account other considerations. If you follow this route, things can be rather grind-y, like "kill  for 10 levels, then ... ". Never be afraid to "just kill stuff" though realize it's never the best option.

Also note that there are several quests that are very worthy of one's attention because of their EXP rewards. Many players use their first, established, character to farm the quest items and then follow the quest line with their new character - this can mean a lvl 10 whatever suddenly jumps to lvl 60 or 70 for some quests depending on your server's rate (x1 ?)

I've played the game for about 3 years, and AFIK there is no "bonus" for fighting creatures above or below your level, unless it's a specific feature of your server. The EXP you get from killing a poring is the same EXP no matter if you're level 1 or lvl 99. Note that the EXP needed to advance to the next level changes, though, so killing a poring at lvl 1 will be very helpful (about 99% exp) while killing a poring at lvl 90 will render about 0% exp.

> 2 - People say that i must level as a two handed sword Knight, using
>   AGI,DEX and STR as my main attribs. Is it that faster to level that
>   way instead of leveling using pikes ?

Yes. Until you get into the lvl 80s and 90s, leveling with pikes cannot compare to leveling with 2H. Understand that Knights are really geared towards 2H with their skills; they do have some lance abilities, but not nearly as many.

You want to expend the least amount of time leveling. These are what leveling builds are for. Once you get to your final levels - rebirthed 90's, then you'll settle down and hone into your build. It can take days to gain a single 1% in the high 90's leveling - this is why you want to get your lower levels done ASAP. There's nothing wrong with having fun, but it's not efficient to level on porings from lvl 1 to 99, you know?

> 3 - Where can i find decent gear/weapons while leveling ? Is there any
>   spot that i might visit to get some gear before a certain level ?

When you're at a low level, anything goes, whatever you can find that works best, supplementing with your equipment shops when needed. Izulde is the best place to find weapons and armor for Knights.

For 2H geared Knights, Glast Heim Chivalry will net you a bunch of equipment in your mid-levels (60-80ish?). Above that, you'll start to hunt specific monsters for the equipment for your build.

> 4 - Are Knights with Pikes, good for PvP or Two Handed Swords ones are
>   Better ?

Neither. Both have their pros and cons, both can win and loose PVP.

> I know there is a table that explains the bonus [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/561051-ragnarok-online/faqs/21546) but i can't handle by myself

I wanted to note the Ragnarok Online is NOT geared for the single individual. If your play style is to kill everything alone, never talk to anyone, never make friends, and do everything yourself, you've taken the hard route on a game that's meant to be social. Find a party, find a guild, do things with others. AFIK there isn't a MVP that can't be solo'ed, but you have to be pretty uber already to do so, and by that point there's little point to solo'ing said MVP other than for lols.

I really felt for you so I wanted to include some other stuff about Rangarok Online:

- Until you know the game very, very well, you are going to suck in PVP. Especially as a knight. Ragnarok is all about one-shotting your opponent dead and then laughing hysterically at their confusion and frustration. I really feel that the game has engineered certain classes to basically dominate PVP.
- Ragnarok isn't a game that a new player can pick up and do just as well as everybody else in. There are numbers and systems for everything, and an experienced player knows those stats and systems for their own benefit. A new player can't possibly pick it all up at the start, but understand that "RTFM" is the very best, most efficient, and fastest way to exceed. The problem is that this "manual" is a collection of webpages scattered all across the internet. There are special pages for special things, but here's the basics for a knight. Don't be afraid to mix and match guides. Sometimes there is a best answer, sometimes there isn't

  - [Leveling Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/561051-ragnarok-online/faqs/21546)
  - [PVP Guide](http://write.ratemyserver.net/ragnoark-online-character-guides/lord-knight-a-comprehensive-guide-for-pvmwoepvp/)
  - [Equipment, Skill, Monster Database](http://ratemyserver.net/index.php?page=mob_db)
  - [EXP Chart](http://irowiki.org/wiki/Base_EXP_Chart)
  - [Build calculator](http://rode.doddlercon.com/db/calc/)
  - [Spiral Pierce FAQ](http://inro.wikidot.com/clashing-spiral-faqs)
- Players who do well in PVP are those who have the best equiptment and builds. These players are rarely "well-rounded" for everything, instead, they have their stats, cards, equiptment, and skills specifically tailored for killing you.